# How to see complete logcat of application in Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse

While executing one application, i got following logcat in eclipse:

```
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):  Process:com.linpusime_tc.android.linpus_tckbd, PID: 24249
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to  create application com.linpusime_tc.android.linpus_tckbd.AnyApplication: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4331)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at and roid.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to java.lang.String
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at android.app.SharedPreferencesImpl.getString(SharedPreferencesImpl.java:224)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at com.linpus_tckbd.ConfigurationImpl.getIntFromString(ConfigurationImpl.java:469)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at com.linpus_tckbd.ConfigurationImpl.handleConfigurationChange(ConfigurationImpl.java:370)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at com.linpus_tckbd.ConfigurationImpl.<init>(ConfigurationImpl.java:98)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at com.linpusime_tc.android.linpus_tckbd.AnyApplication.onCreate(AnyApplication.java:61)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1007)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    at   android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4328)
07-02 10:01:46.273: E/AndroidRuntime(24249):    ... 10 more
```

I want to see complete lines(at the end) of logcat?. Any suggestion

Comment: why do you need to see more? the error in your code is line 98 of ConfigurationImpl.java

Comment: Because i didn't modify some other class which affects this method.Thats why

Comment: Debug the application. If you get the `Exception` the app should suspend the thread before finally closing it (as far as I remember twice, you'll want to investigate the second time then). You should be able to get the full stacktrace using `getStacktrace()` for the exception in the "Expressions" tab. (the Exception should show up as `e` or `ex` in the "Variables" tab)